# Reading files with windows and unix line endings on iOS/OSX

Tags: ios, macos, unix, text-files, line-endings

I have these lines to read a file and split its lines into items of an array:

```
- (NSArray *)lerLinhasArquivoBundle:(NSString *)nomeArquivo {

    NSString *arquivo = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *bd = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nomeArquivo ofType:@"csv"];

    if (bd) {
        arquivo = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:bd
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                               error:&error];
    }

    if (error || !bd) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [arquivo componentsSeparatedByString: @"\r\n"];
}
```

the problem is that this will only work with files that have "windows" CR/LF endings and will fail for files with UNIX line endings. When the file is a UNIX one, I get just one big item on the array.

OK, I can hack the method to test for `\r\n` and just `\n` and use the one that gives me more items on the array, but that appears to be a lame solution.

Is there a way to **know** what line endings is being used and use that information on the return line to split the elements into the array?

Comment: What does `return  [arquivo componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];` do?

Comment: aha!!! that's it. Please add this commend as an answer! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` rather than an explicit string:

```
return  [arquivo componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```